# Which enzymes use ATP?

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, enzymes, bioenergetics, energy-metabolism

It is well known that there are many enzymes which use ATP in their function, and any enzyme that work against an energy gradient need to have that energy supplied from somewhere, but just as well there are enzymes that simply work spontaneously and do not require such an influx of energy. However I can't seem to find any sort of list, however brief, that contains examples of enzymes that use ATP and ones that do not, or any indication of their prevalence. I could go one by one through each of the commonly encountered enzymes in the cell, but that would be tedious.

Is there any source where I could find what I am looking for? Or at the very least which of the major enzymes in the protein transcription/synthesis chain require ATP?

Comment: This would be such a massive list I can't see why you would maintain such a thing. It's possible someone will have an answer to how to extract it from a bioinformatics database, though.

Comment: I agree with @BryanKrause but both he and I gave examples of ATP-utilizing enzymes in our answers to a [different question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/59492/is-it-a-valid-generalization-that-kinases-catalyse-reactions-involving-energy-tr). This might be a starting point. However please finish reading the [Tour] and the help on asking questions here. We are keen on people showing evidence of having tried to answer their question themselves.

Comment: I just searched the Expasy Enzyme site for ATP using this search [page](https://enzyme.expasy.org/cgi-bin/enzyme/enzyme-search-ca). Will take you a while to look through them although there were fewer answers than I expected.

Comment: Thank you, David's answer was just what I was looking for. However I should have expected the daunting task of picking out a set of examples from that list. Any chance of being able to sort by a criteria like papers cited or times cross referenced, to a get some sense of importance?